# advanced selector doesn't match using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three ids in DOM, but somehow this code don't work? No error

```
$(function() {
  console.log('test')

  $('[div][id*="sohai"]').each(function() {
  console.log($(this))
})
})
```

https://jsbin.com/bumoyezena/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Add all code that is necessary to reproduce the error/problem in your question ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and not only parts of it with a link to an external source - which by the way is also incomplete...

Comment: There's no error because it's a valid selector. It just doesn't select what you want. More: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: Voting to close as no-repro/unlikely to help others in future.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `[]` surrounding the `div` selector

```js
$(function() {
  console.log('test')
  
  $('div[id*="sohai"]').each(function() {
  //^---^--------------------
     console.log(this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sohai-1"></div>
<div id="sohai-2"></div>
<div id="sohai-3"></div>
```